# What percentage of home computers are awake at any given time?

Tags: networking, p2p, file-sharing

If I am making a p2p file sharing application, I need to know how many regular home computers must I replicate a file on for it to be ALMOST ALWAYS available. Any idea?

Comment: I think a pure number is invalid, unique networks are more important.  For example *x* million users in one nation are not useful if the nation brings up a new [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China).  Similarly what happens with [Tier 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier_1_network) splits?

Comment: Please, don't vote to close P2P questions if you don't have experience with P2P. Some questions are naturally broad and you should accept this rather than trying to apply SO rules blindly. It does not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to evaluate, because it is not only a question of being awake, it is also a question of being reachable and of workload capacity and bandwidth. It is not because a PC has the file and that's it is online that it will be able to deliver the file (especially if it is a big file).

This kind of info is impossible to guess from a theoretical perspective. The best approach is to measure it from your live system. But, if you really need some estimation, an average user would open its PC between 7-9 AM and shut it down between 20-23 PM, with may be a couple of hours off during the day.

You may want to Google about P2P CHURN. There is some theory out there that could help you create some model, but honestly, in my experience, there is nothing like concrete/real data.